# Set value to the field using annotation

Tags: java, annotations

I have an application which convert values from one one format to another. This conversion is required at the time of receiving an input or sending an output. I want to use annotations for this purpose. 
The requirement is to create a custom annotation that can reset the value of the field, the annotation is linked to, after conversion based on some value, e.g.

```
@Convert(value = "butter")
String meal;
```

So, if meal = "bread" when it is received in the request, it should be converted to "bread n butter" and then passed on for further processing.

I did try to search it on google but did not find anything useful. Though I have worked on custom annotations for validation but that doesn't suit the requirement here. I am looking for a way to program such a custom annotation and not aware of any interface, similar to one when we write custom validation annotations, that could be implemented for this purpose.

Comment: see attribute converter implementation in hibernate, it will give an idea

Comment: @Saravana this looks useful. thanks for the info. will check this out. many thanks.

Comment: @Saravana Is it possible to do the conversion based on some parameter like an enum?